# cProfile for Python does not recognize Function name

Tags: python, profiling, cprofile

I have a function in an app called email which I want to profile.  When I try to do something like this, it blows up

```
   from django.core.management import BaseCommand
   import cProfile


  class Command(BaseCommand):
       def handle(self, *args, **options):
           from email.modname import send_email
           cProfile.run('send_email(user_id=1, city_id=4)')
```

When I run this management command, it throws the following error:

```
      exec cmd in globals, locals
     File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
     NameError: name 'send_email' is not defined
```

What am I missing here? How does cProfile evaluate the string (look up func names in the global/local namespace)?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The problem is that you imported `send_email` inside your method definition.

I suggest you to use `runctx`:

```
cProfile.runctx('send_email()', None, locals())
```

From [the official documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html#cProfile.runctx):

```
cProfile.runctx(command, globals, locals, filename=None)
```

*This function is similar to run(), with added arguments to supply the globals and locals dictionaries for the command string.*

Comment: for me:
cProfile.runctx('send_email()', globals(), locals(), filename=None)